# REST: best practice for publishing data model

Tags: api, rest, data-structures, avro

What are some best practices to publish the data model of a REST API?

I thought of adding a method to the REST API, which returns a plain text containing the Avro schema description (.avsc) for each method offered by the API.

Or what are better approaches to offer information about the data structure returned by a REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Swagger (http://swagger.io/), Blue Print (https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint) or RAML (http://raml.org/) depending on your preferences.

Comment: Also [Slate](https://github.com/tripit/slate) and [Apiary](http://apiary.io/) are other interesting alternatives